# Recurring conditional probability calculation

Tags: python, probability

I would like to do some conditional probability calcution which as following:

```
def calx(prob1, prob2, prob3, prob4):
    first_selection = prob1
    second_selection = prob2*(prob1/(1-prob2))+prob3*(prob1/(1-prob3))+prob4*(prob1/(1-prob4))
    third_selection = prob2*(prob3/(1-prob2))*(prob1/(1-prob2-prob3))
                      +prob3*(prob2/(1-prob3))*(prob1/(1-prob2-prob3))
                      +prob3*(prob4/(1-prob3))*(prob1/(1-prob3-prob4))
                      +prob4*(prob3/(1-prob4))*(prob1/(1-prob3-prob4))
                      +prob2*(prob4/(1-prob2))*(prob1/(1-prob2-prob4))
                      +prob4*(prob2/(1-prob4))*(prob1/(1-prob2-prob4))

    return first_selection+second_selection+third_selection

calx(.5,.4,.05,.05)
```

[image: the image link of the generalized math equation]

The situation is about picking balls with different colors from a box. There are three shots for picking a ball with a particular color. Once a ball is picked, all the balls with that color will be removed from the box. The above equation is for 12 different colors of 100 balls in the box. I don't wanna code all the combinations which should be redundant as I believe there is a more efficient to do this.

Is there any methods will make this way less complicated?

Comment: Can you write a mathematical for above probabilities if so add them in the question

Comment: The code that you included doesn't seem to have any obvious relation to the rest of the question.

Comment: Also -- you shouldn't quote someone's answer without attribution and you should also consider accepting their answer to the [question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612672/294695) in  Mathematics.

Comment: Then we should all abandon our computer and  go back to the time we do our paper work. Isn't the computer was invented for doing complicated and redundant math work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly attribute QED's answer. Also: do you want to supply the quantities of each color of ball to your function? If not, and you want to consider that an unknown, are all possible combinations equally likely? Things start getting much more complex there.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` can help to assemble the terms in the sum. Care must be taken in implementing a 1-based mathematical formula using 0-based Python:

```
import itertools

def p(i,N):
    '''computes P(C_3 = i). N is a list of 12 nums summing to 100'''
    total = 0
    s = set(range(1,13)) - set([i])
    for j,k in itertools.product(s,repeat = 2):
        if j != k:
            term = N[i-1]/(100 - N[j-1] - N[k-1])*N[j-1]/(100 - N[k-1])*N[k-1]/100
            total += term
    return total

#test:

N = [5,10,10,5,20,10,5,5,5,5,5,15]
for i in range(1,13):
    print(f'P(C_3 = {i}) = {p(i,N)}')

'''
P(C_3 = 1) = 0.058068956327470306
P(C_3 = 2) = 0.10283873333408944
P(C_3 = 3) = 0.10283873333408944
P(C_3 = 4) = 0.05806895632747032
P(C_3 = 5) = 0.15139318885448905
P(C_3 = 6) = 0.10283873333408945
P(C_3 = 7) = 0.0580689563274703
P(C_3 = 8) = 0.0580689563274703
P(C_3 = 9) = 0.0580689563274703
P(C_3 = 10) = 0.0580689563274703
P(C_3 = 11) = 0.0580689563274703
P(C_3 = 12) = 0.1336079168509509
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of itertools module. I have learned that I can do effcient iteration afterward by using it.